# LMDE does not boot directly after install, but boots from cd option "boot from local hard drive"

Tags: linux-mint, boot, system-installation

Just got a new (used) pc from my job.
Still a nice beast, Intel board with Core 2 quad CPU and 4G of RAM.

So I came to install Linux Mint Debian Edition on it.

The live CD works like a charm, and install without problem. But when I reboot, I just have a blinking cursor on a black screen and nothing happens. Grub never shows up.

Try reinstalling with grub on `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sda1`, same thing.

Then I reinserted the live CD, and from the first menu I select "boot from local hard drive". Magic makes its effect, my newly installed LMDE boots correctly.

Rebooted, same thing happened.

Seems like BIOS problem, but for me all settings seems ok.

I have the vista oem disk but I did not tried it.

Did someone have an idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, that I just forgot the boot flag on the partition.